# image and inverse image of set

Tags: calculus

a)Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2+1$ so $f([-1,1])=[1,2]$

b)let $f:[0,+∞) \to \mathbb R$ and $f(x)=x^2$ so, $f^{-1}([-1,1])=\{1\}$

I spent a lot of time to understand that how it solve like that ?

Comment: Please try to formulate your question in such a manner that we can understand it, otherwise we won't be able to help.

Comment: Are you sure you want $f^{-1}$ in b it looks strange as the function is not bijective.

Comment: yes,I am sure 100%,this example from my book ,but it does not justified the answer.just it gives the answer direct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the tags (general-topology) and (functional-analysis) are much more advanced areas of mathematics.

For part a, I recommend plugging in values from $[-1, 1]$ into $f(x) = x^2$. You'll see that the range must be $[0,1]$. Add one to both ends and you will get your desired range.

Part b is a little different. Since no positive real number has a negative square root, $f^{-1}([-1,0)) = \emptyset$. Can you see why the range must be $[0,1]$?

Comment: because f(x)=x^2